# Changing $\cos(\theta)$ into a Complex Polar Exponential

Tags: complex-numbers

How would we take $\cos(\theta)$ and turn it into $\exp(i \theta)$?

I think it might have something to do with the idea that if we have a complex number, $z$, and we take the $\operatorname*{Re}(z)$, we can equate the polar form and polar exponential forms so that we end up with:

$$\cos(\theta) = \operatorname*{Re}(\exp(i \theta))$$

---

**Edit:** To give an example, I want to know how they got from:

$$E_{\text{tot}}=E_1+E_2$$
$$E_{\text{tot}}=A_1\cos(\omega t+\phi_1)+A_2\cos(\omega t+\phi_2)$$

To:

$$E_{\text{tot}}=A_1 e^{i (\omega t+\phi_1)}+A_2 e^{i (\omega t+\phi_2)}$$

Comment: Are you asking how to derive Euler's formulas (for example $\cos(\theta) = \frac{e^{i \theta} + e^{-i \theta}}{2}$) ?

Comment: I don't think so. I already know how to do that. What I want to know is how to get from: http://prntscr.com/eu79qj
To here: http://prntscr.com/eu79tm

How did they change the cosines into a polar exponential complex number?

Comment: From the examples there it's hard to say. $\cos(\theta)$ is generally not $e^{i \theta}$. one guess is that they are looking at a differential equation and switching between considering real-valued and complex-valued solutions